# background-color stops working when changing from "display: table-cell" to "float: left"

Tags: css

I was trying to do swim lanes but it doesnt work when using float. According to w3schools it should work regardless of type.

[Here's my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a9z8kb6p/)

And the code from above fiddle, html...

```
<div>
  <div class="table-row">
    <div class="float">1</div>
    <div class="float">2</div>
    <div class="float">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="table-row">
    <div class="float">1</div>
    <div class="float">2</div>
    <div class="float">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="table-row">
    <div class="float">1</div>
    <div class="float">2</div>
    <div class="float">3</div>
  </div>
</div>
<br/>
<br/>
<div>
  <div class="table-row">
    <div class="table-cell">1</div>
    <div class="table-cell">2</div>
    <div class="table-cell">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="table-row">
    <div class="table-cell">1</div>
    <div class="table-cell">2</div>
    <div class="table-cell">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="table-row">
    <div class="table-cell">1</div>
    <div class="table-cell">2</div>
    <div class="table-cell">3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css...

```
.table-row {
  clear: both;
}

.table-row:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: rgb(200,203,207);
}

.float {
    float: left;
}

.table-cell {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

EDIT:

I've tried, in the fiddle, the overflow auto and clear fix classes as per the "This question already has an answer" answers. None of them work.

Comment: The background-color property is working fine as always. Your `.table-row` elements simply don’t have any height any more - _because_ all children have been floated.

Comment: I've tried using the "clearfix" suggestions but they aren't working.

Comment: Well then you most likely simply didn’t manage to apply them correctly … For example the version using `overflow:hidden` works quite fine, https://jsfiddle.net/rmhgst20/